# Are databases hosted with Heroku Postgres persistent?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, heroku

I am building an app on Heroku (with Node.JS) and need persistent data storage. I would have liked to use Redis, but this is a small app and don't want to have to pay for persistence. Is Postgres the same? As in, are Postgres databases persistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That's pretty much the #1 goal of PostgreSQL, stability and persistence.